# In GCP VM /var/log taking more space. How to reduce it?

Tags: linux, logging, google-cloud-platform

I'm using GCE of disk space 50GB. and /var/log alone takes 12GB of space.

can anyone tell me what are those below files?

```
alternatives.log       auth.log.1     daemon.log       debug.1     dpkg.log.2.gz   kern.log.1     mail.err.1      mail.info.4.gz  mail.warn       messages.2.gz  syslog.2.gz  unattended-upgrades  wtmp
alternatives.log.1     auth.log.2.gz  daemon.log.1     debug.2.gz  dpkg.log.3.gz   kern.log.2.gz  mail.err.2.gz   mail.log        mail.warn.1     messages.3.gz  syslog.3.gz  user.log             wtmp.1
alternatives.log.2.gz  auth.log.3.gz  daemon.log.2.gz  debug.3.gz  exim4           kern.log.3.gz  mail.info       mail.log.1      mail.warn.2.gz  messages.4.gz  syslog.4.gz  user.log.1
alternatives.log.3.gz  auth.log.4.gz  daemon.log.3.gz  debug.4.gz  faillog         kern.log.4.gz  mail.info.1     mail.log.2.gz   mail.warn.3.gz  ntpstats       syslog.5.gz  user.log.2.gz
apt                    btmp           daemon.log.4.gz  dpkg.log    fontconfig.log  lastlog        mail.info.2.gz  mail.log.3.gz   messages        syslog         syslog.6.gz  user.log.3.gz
auth.log               btmp.1         debug            dpkg.log.1  kern.log        mail.err       mail.info.3.gz  mail.log.4.gz   messages.1      syslog.1       syslog.7.gz  user.log.4.gz
```

and what happen if I remove them?

or can I remove only .gz file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this Logrotate tutorial https://www.linode.com/docs/uptime/logs/use-logrotate-to-manage-log-files. You can use `size` to force log rotation when it grows bigger than the specified `[value]`, also you can use `rotate` to control how many times a log is rotated before old logs are removed (**If you set it to 0 logs will be removed immediately after they are rotated**).

Comment: daemon.log taking more than 10GB can I delete old .gz files

Comment: Yes, but if you properly configure Logrotate if could be done automatically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/var/log/daemon.log taking more space how to reduce it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60560729/var-log-daemon-log-taking-more-space-how-to-reduce-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can anyone tell me what are those below files?

No, because they depend of what software is installed. But some of them are very important, for example auth.log records authorization tries, daemon.log logs daemons activity, and so on. They serve for debugging, accounting and so on.

> and what happen if I remove them?

Probably nothing dangerous, especially those like .1 .2 or .old.gz and so on. But `logrotate` would be the correct solution to try; depending on the distribution it can be easy to use (just install the package) or it may require quite hand-made configuration.