# /var/log/daemon.log taking more space how to reduce it?

Tags: linux, logging, google-cloud-platform, var

below are the files

```
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm  4.4G Mar  6 09:04 daemon.log
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm  6.2G Mar  1 06:26 daemon.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm   50M Feb 23 06:26 daemon.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm   41M Feb 17 06:25 daemon.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm   72K Feb  9 06:25 daemon.log.4.gz
```

how can I remove it? will it affect if I directly delete it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the difference between this question and your previous [In GCP VM /var/log taking more space. How to reduce it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559965/in-gcp-vm-var-log-taking-more-space-how-to-reduce-it)?

Comment: Update `logrotate` configuration to run on specific, frequent time interval and compress the file based on the size of the mentioned file.

Comment: ...anyway, I bet you can safely delete them, especially the last 3.

Comment: Some tips: 1) You might want to examine the log files to see why the jump in size compared to previous weeks. 2) Use logrotate on a more frequent schedule to reduce individual log file size. 3) Log files should be moved off instances. Look into Stackdriver or similar products for log management.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to manage the logs would be to use Logrotate

This is [Serhii's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559965/in-gcp-vm-var-log-taking-more-space-how-to-reduce-it#comment107141394_60559965) on your other similar question:

> Have a look at [this Logrotate tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/uptime/logs/use-logrotate-to-manage-log-files)
> linode.com/docs/uptime/logs/use-logrotate-to-manage-log-files. You can
> use `size` to force log rotation when it grows bigger than the
> specified `[value]`, also you can use `rotate` to control how many
> times a log is rotated before old logs are removed (**If you set it to
> 0 logs will be removed immediately after they are rotated**).

**You can delete the logs** but depending on the software you're running - if some of it needs some part of logs or utilises them in any way - if you delete them it will stop working as intended.

**You can also have a look at the logs** and analyse them to see which software writes the most data and try to reconfigure it so the number of logs info generated will drop significantly. That - combined with `logrorate` should yield satisfactory results.

And if that's not enough **you can store your logs in a [bucket](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets)** and [mount it as a disk](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) in your VM's filesystem. That way any software installed on your VM will be able to write to it.

But this will incur some [charges for using the bucket storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing) so keep that in mind.